# How do I identify brand/type of bathtub faucet?

Tags: plumbing

I have a cartridge type of bathtub faucet and both the hot and cold cartridges need to be replaced. Unfortunately, the faucet has no branding marks on it at all. At one point I had removed the cartridge and took it into a plumbing supply store, but was unable to find a match. Also, the clerk at the plumbing supply store said that by knowing the brand, they would be able to determine a match. (Also, the sink, towel rack, valves, and toilet all match and none of it is branded.)

How do I determine the faucet brand? Does anyone know of an online resource that works as a "field guide" to faucets?

Another note: the toilet and sink fixtures are designer branded "Jacob Dalafon", but I was told at the plumbing supply store that will not determine the faucet branding.

Comment: How about posting a picture? Someone on here might recognize it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that as soon as my cam battery charges up.

Answer (score 1):

When I needed to replace valve stems in my bathtub faucet, there was a logo on the cleanout/overflow cover.  I took a picture of that with me to the plumbing supply store.  They recognized the logo and could match up the stem in a few minutes.

Comment: Seriously, there are NO logos on any of this plumbing! We're walking away from it and replacing the stupid jacuzzi tub with a walk-in shower. However, it looks like we can get a good match on the tile....so if luck holds out, we won't need to re-tile the entire bathroom.

Answer (score 0):

Might be Kohler: http://www.us.kohler.com/morebusiness/delafon_geographic.jsp

Comment: Seems to be an EU brand, are you in Europe or elsewhere?

Comment: Couldn't find anything to work. We're rebuilding the whole thing. Replacing the original tub/jacuzzi with a walk/in shower. Meanwhile, looking forward to fun removing tile that was solidly installed.